# Black Box when animating WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

So, I'm animating a window opening, and the animation looks perfect for what I'm trying to do except for one crucial part... the space between where the window *will* be and where it currently is in the animation is a black box.

I've googled quite a bit but I don't see this issue mentioned anywhere!

I've tried this in a standard window as well, no difference other than the black box only shows within the window border. I have zero codebehind other than whatever Visual Studio generated for me.

Here's my window:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Schedule.MainWindow"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="mainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" x:Name="winTransform1"/>
</Window.RenderTransform>

<Window.RenderTransformOrigin>
    <Point X=".5" Y=".5"/>
</Window.RenderTransformOrigin>

<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger SourceName="mainWindow" RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Name="openBoard">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="winTransform1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                                 From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger> 
</Window.Triggers>

<Grid> 

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the Windows `AllowsTransparency` property to true so you don't get the black background.

```
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" >
```

**However** `AllowsTransparency` only works for `WindowStyle.None` so you will lose the default windows border for your application, I don't think there is another way around that, but you can easily make a custom window style with close/minimize etc. buttons

Comment: You're awesome! Also, conveniently, I swapped to using Modern UI for WPF and it continues to handle the window border for me even when WindowStyle is None.